How to find the probability of each of the each prediction in Simple Transformer based NER Model
I have given the code snippet below which i am using at the time of prediction where i am getting the raw output for each word as well as predictions.
from simpletransformers.ner import NERModel
cuda_available = torch.cuda.is_available()

## Load Model
header_model = NERModel("bert", HeaderModel_path ,use_cuda=cuda_available)

predictions, raw_output = header_model.predict([header_string])```

